# Riemann Integration on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Prove that the function f defined on [0, 1] by
f(x) = sgn(sin(1/x)), 0<x<=1 and f(x)= 0, x = 0
is Riemann integrable on [0, 1], where sgn denotes the signum function.

I consider the partition {0,1/nπ,1/(n-1)π,...,1/3π,1/2π,1/π,1} and proved that the given function is Riemann integrable on [1/nπ,1] but not able to prove it for [0,1]. Since f is continuous on [1/nπ,1] except at the set of points  1/nπ, 1/(n-1)π, ..., 1/3π, 1/2π, 1/π which have only one limit point, 0, and hence f is Riemann integrable on [1/nπ,1]. But f achieves both 1 and -1   on [0,1/nπ) and is not continuous.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions

Comment: You should find the discontinuities of the function and notice that the set of discontinuities has only one limit point (namely $0$). This should help to prove that it is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Please visit the [mathjax tutorial especially designed for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/72031) and typeset math using mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

This function is Riemann-integrable by the [Lebesgue-Vitali theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability)